# incorporating .w files into a Java program

Tags: java, import

I am having trouble finding out what these .w files are and how to using them with my Java code: see Assignment1.zip at http://see.stanford.edu/see/materials/icspmcs106a/assignments.aspx

I would post a screenshot of my files, but I don't have enough "reputation points" to post an image on this site--I usually just read answers from others b/c I'm just learning.  I can't open these .w files or else I would paste some of their contents in here.

For the past year, I've worked a good amount with Python and C++, but I decided to learn some Java from these free Stanford online lectures: http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111.

I've looked all over and simply cannot find out what .w files are, and I haven't been able to open them.  I realize they're clearly worlds for the graphical robot to move around in, but I can't get the .java & .class files to function with these .w (or "world") files.

I would be happy to post some of my code in here as well, if you want.  And I could post an image of the files & folders once I get a good enough reputation.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: did you try opening the files in a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the documentation for `karel.jar`.  There is already code for reading and working with these files, in `sandford.karel.KarelWorld` there is a `load(File)` method.  But you will need to be working with the rest of the classes in the jar file, too, so you'll need to look for documentation (maybe given in the lecture videos?) or you'll have a very frustrating time.